# What should we write in our "about" page?

Tags: discussion, new-users

There's a new "about" page available here: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/about

The top bit is editable by moderators. It currently says:

> **Skeptics** is a question and answer site for applying scientific skepticism. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers challenging unreferenced notable claims, pseudoscience and biased results.

What should we write in there?

Context:

- [What should we put on our Tour page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164778)
- [We're rolling out a new "Quick Start" guide to help new users learn the basics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163254)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to take a stab at this. First, to the original formulation.

> Skeptics is a question and answer site for applying scientific skepticism. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers challenging unreferenced notable claims, pseudoscience and biased results.

Respectfully, some objections: skeptics "apply scientific skepticism" is awkward. The site is not technically built by the users. Build and q&a are repeated twice in two sentences.

With this in mind, I suggest the following rewrite:

> Skeptics is an open forum dedicated to challenging notable unsupported claims, debunking pseudoscience, and exposing biased findings. Written and moderated by the community, we are a part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites.